# How do you view your folders uploaded to AWS Management Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I made a recent deploy to AWS Lambda and need to view the folders which were uploaded in order to troubleshoot.

When viewing the code source, all I see is:

[image]

Is there any other way besides the code editor where it lists the folders and resources that have been uploaded to AWS Lambda after a deployment?

Comment: The serverless framework uploads a zip file for the Lambda deployment. That zip file should still be on your local machine where it was created as part of the deployment. You can simply open that zip file to view the folders inside. I don't use the Serverless Framework myself, so I'm not sure what location it places the zip file in, on your local computer.

Comment: In addition to what @MarkB said, you can also download the zip file from the console

Comment: Another idea, make your deployment package smaller! Separate the dependencies from the code using Layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload your code in the AWS console when you create the Lambda function, then it is stored in an Amazon S3 location that you cannot access. You can't access the Lambda service's S3 bucket(s) directly, but you can download the code you previously uploaded to your Lambda function.

Go to the AWS Lambda console -> select your Lambda function -> then click Actions -> Export function -> click Download deployment package. Note: if your code was written in Java (or other compiled language) then the download will contain compiled files, not the original source code.
[image: Export Source code]

If you upload your source code to your own S3 bucket before creating the Lambda function, then you will know the path to your source code.